# Flex RichTextEditor throws Error : FTETextField does not support setting type to "input"

Tags: apache-flex, rich-text-editor

I'm currently working with Flex 4.6.0.

I'm trying to add a RichTextEditor component to my application but when I run it, it freezes and throws this error :

> Error: FTETextField does not support setting type to "input".

Do you have any idea what causes it, and how to get rid of it ?

Thanks !

Edit :
The code is simply the following :

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           xmlns:comps="comps.*"
                       xmlns:views="views.*"
           width="100%" height="100%">

<fx:Style source="design.css"/>

<s:layout>
<s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"
                  paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingRight="10" paddingLeft="10"/>
</s:layout>


<s:Label text="My app" fontSize="20" fontWeight="bold"/>

<mx:RichTextEditor />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Sure - post edited. Even with this simplest code I get the error.

Comment: A little late, but it's because of your CSS.

Comment: Never too late! Can you tell me more?